# C# - add new row to dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I have this code :

```
    DataRow myNewRow;
    myNewRow = hRAddNewDataSet.Vication.NewRow();
    myNewRow["EmployeeID"] = Convert.ToInt32(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
    myNewRow["VicationDate"] = vicationDateDateTimePicker.Value;
    myNewRow["VicationSubject"] = vicationSubjectTextBox.Text;
    myNewRow["VicationType"] = Convert.ToInt32(vicationTypeComboBox.SelectedValue);
    myNewRow["Time"] = Convert.ToInt32(timeTextBox.Text);
    myNewRow["VicationAs"] = Convert.ToInt32(vicationAsComboBox.SelectedValue);
    myNewRow["StatementNo"] = statementNoTextBox.Text;
    myNewRow["StatementDate"] = statementDateDateTimePicker.Value;
    myNewRow["Info"] = infoTextBox.Text;
    hRAddNewDataSet.Vication.Rows.Add(myNewRow);
```

When I run this code, it will add new row as I want but it will also update the current row depends on the value of

```
vicationBindingSource.Position
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Might want to refactor `vication` to `vacation`

Comment: @B Tyler: Why I whould do that??

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "update the current row"? setting another row as current? updating values in the current row?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: yes, it will update values in the current row

Comment: is there a databinding between your controls on the form and that bindingsource?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: yes, there is datagrid control and table adapter

Comment: ok, more precisely: is there a databinding between the datatable/dataset and one of the controls in your code example above? (like employeeIDTextBox)

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: yes, they are connected also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since there is a databinding all your changes to the bound properties of the controls will be written to the datasource (normally after successful validation of the control)

so when you enter the values of you new row, you are actually changing the values of the current row first

you should add your row by using the `AddNew()` method of your `BindingSource`

Comment: Where I should call this method? this method doesn't need any parameters, so where I should add it?

Comment: well, i don't know your application, but when you call AddNew() a new row will be inserted into your datatable and this new row will become the current row. so you will possibly want to put that call in a click handler, bound to a button's Click event